# how to change title of table generated with pander::pander

Tags: r, localization

When I plot a table with the following function:

````
```{r}
PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES<-
read.table("PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES1.csv",  header=TRUE, sep=",")
-```


```{r}
pander::pander(PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES)

```
````

[a table like this is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfQzY.png)

I would like to know how to change the title, so instead of "Table 1: Table continues below", "Tabla de producto interno bruto" appears as the title.

Another question I have is how to change the part "continues below" to its Spanish language equivalent  "continuará abajo"

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `help(panderOptions, pander)` is useful to you.

Here is my example:

````
```{r}
PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES <-
  read.table("PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES1.csv",  header=TRUE, sep=",")

pander::panderOptions("table.continues.affix", "(continuará abajo)")
```

```{r}
pander::pander(PIBPORSECTORPRECIOSCORRIENTES, 
               caption = "Tabla de producto interno bruto")
```
````